# How to copy email info to Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have the following code to get email info from a specific sender. I cannot manage to copy the info to Excel.

I can see the info in the immediate window but nothing else.

```vb
Sub Getemaildetails()

Dim ol As Outlook.Application
Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
Dim fol As Outlook.Folder
Dim i As Object
Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Filtertext As String

Set ol = New Outlook.Application
Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("Mapi")
Set fol = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Filtertext = "[SenderName]= 'Eskalem Bogale'"

Set i = fol.Items.Find(Filtertext)

Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Clear

If i Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Nothing was found.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

If i.Class <> olMail Then
    MsgBox "Item is not an email.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

Set mi = i

Debug.Print mi.Subject

End Sub
```

Comment: So, do you need all emails coming from that specific sender?

Comment: Hello! sorry, I just saw this. Yes, I want only emails from this specific sender

Comment: Then, did you test the code I posted?

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not try clarifying my clarification question, I only assumes that I correctly understood what you need. Meaning to return date from all received emails from that specific sender. It should be very fast, placing the data in an array and then dropping the processing result at once:

```
Sub GetEmaildetails()
Dim ol As Outlook.Application, ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim fol As Outlook.folder, i As Outlook.items, arrM
Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem, Filtertext As String, iEm As Long

Set ol = New Outlook.Application
Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("Mapi")
Set fol = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Filtertext = "[SenderName]= 'Eskalem Bogale'"
'You can also use:
'Filtertext = "[From] = 'Eskalem Bogale'"

Set i = fol.items.Restrict(Filtertext)

Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Clear

If i Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Nothing was found.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

ReDim arrM(1 To i.count + 1, 1 To 3)
iEm = 2
For Each mi In i
   arrM(iEm, 1) = mi.Subject
   arrM(iEm, 2) = mi.ReceivedTime
   arrM(iEm, 3) = mi.size
   iEm = iEm + 1
   'it can also return Body, Catetories...
Next
Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrM), 3).Value = arrM
MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Comment: @Mariana Anaya Villafaña: Didn't the above code return what you need?